# dot env variables in CI/CD runtime environment

Tags: vue.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to setup a CI/CD with GitLab and what I want to achieve is to replace all the variables in .env.production file with the ones stored in the Gitlab environment variable.
I search a lot and I could not find any specific example for Vuejs. Anyone did this already, or knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hereafter is an exemple of one of my .gitlab-ci.yaml :

```
build:
  stage: build
  image: node:12.18.3-buster
  script:
    # Set environment variables
    - export VUE_APP_API_BASE_PATH="$API_BASE_PATH"

    - npm install
    - npm run build

    - tar -zcf dist.tar.gz dist
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 15 min
    paths:
      - dist.tar.gz
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: thanks, I will test it out and see if it works for me! I will accept as an answer if works for me!

Comment: Do this work, set the variables like this, and use it in runtime?

Comment: yep, environment variables are used during build time